# What does "each following year" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this statement mean?

> A non-refundable tuition deposit will be required each following year to secure a place.

Does it mean that the deposit will need to be paid every year or every alternate year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deposit is to be paid each year. If it were to be paid in alternate years, the phrase used would be "in alternate years" or "every other year" or "every second year".

Answer (score 1):

It means "each year" after the current year. The "following" basically means "after this year", but because you probably already paid the deposit for this (current) year, then it says "each following year", so that you know that its a recurring deposit, but since its non-refundable, its more like a fee that you pay and never get back.